# Replacing a dll in a SilverLight application (xap) for the purpose of sniffing traffic

Tags: c#, silverlight, sniffing, xap

I'm trying to understand how a Silverlight app communicates with its server. Communication is encrypted. I would like to see how messages look like before encryption. I came up with this idea: when browser requests the .xap file, I serve a version containing a patched DLL that does not encrypt anything. I created this DLL by patching C# code with reflexil.

What tool should I use to deliver this patched .xap file? Fiddler? Only one file needs to be replaced, all other requests from the browser should go to the original server.

Is there a simpler way of doing this? For example, does anyone know, where exactly DLL files from .xap files are extracted? How are they loaded? Perhaps it's easier to find where they get extracted and patch the already unpacked version? I used process monitor, but IE seems to be unpacking XAPs in memory.

EDIT:

I did not create the application, that's the problem. I want trick IE into loading a patched version of a DLL from the original XAP.

Comment: If you have created the Silverlight app yourself, you should not have much difficulties to replace a dll before deploying it, by creating different build configurations of your solution...

Answer (score 1):

Don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve, but with regards to your last question on unpacking XAPs, you can access the downloaded xap files in the following location

C:\Documents and Settings[UserName]\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\

rename the package to .zip instead of .xap, unzip, and access your dll there?

Comment: If I patch the dll and repack the XAP, will IE load the patched DLL, or will it download the XAP again from the server?